# My php controller can't include css files

Tags: php, .htaccess, segments

The following issue is driving me crazy, perhaps i am thinking to difficult.

Here is the thing, i developed a small MVC framework that works fine. Atleast without url rewriting.

The problem is that as soon as i use url rewrite, things like the css or images which are included in the templates are directed to the wrong directory.

If i type for example: http://www.domain.com/home then everything is fine and the css file get loaded from the http://www.domain.com/css/ directory.

But when i type: http://www.domain.com/home/ the css file won't be loaded, since its looking for the css files in http://www.domain.com/home/css/ Which is obliviously the wrong directory. It seems it sees home/ as a directory where it looks for the the included files.

If i don't use any url rewriting at all, just by typing: http://www.domain.com/index.php?slugs=home/ then there are no problems at all. So i don't think the problem is caused by my script so thats why i think the problems should be looked for in the .htaccess file.

Here is my htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /astrostrategy/index.php?slugs=$1 [L]
```

Is there a way, that home/test/whatever(The segments) are not seen as a directory?

Hope my post made sense, i often think to complicated :P

Already thanx for any help! :)

Gr,
Hermes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Death's answer doesn't work you can always set the [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) to the url to use in relative paths

Comment: Yesterday i tried it, but somehow this also didn't work. Until today! Seems i where to frustrated and over looked something. But now finally i found a solution ;) thanx!

Answer (score 2):

it seems you're using relative to currect directory path for css. when you use http://www.domain.com/home/ browser takes `home` as directory and css file will be located in `http://www.domain.com/home/css/`.  my suggestion is use relative to root path. Now you're using  something like :

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.main.css" />
```

it's better to use absolute path or relative to root path.

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.main.css" />
```

Comment: I defined all my path's already inside a config file, which in the end also defines in in the same way as you explain. The main issue is that, if i enter let say http://www.domain.com/forum it will look for the css folder inside the forum directory.